# npm build with Browserify - Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, browserify

When running npm build with:

```
"build": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] app/assets/app.jsx -o public/javascripts/app.js"
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'components/maininput.jsx' from 'C:\Users\Work\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project\app\assets'
```

Project structure looks like this:

```
app
|
└────assets
    │   app.jsx
    |
    └───components 
           maininput.jsx
```

import in app.jsx looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { MainInput } from '../components/maininput.jsx'
```

export in maininput.jsx looks like this:

```
export default class MainInput extends React.Component {
  //some code and render()
}
```

I also created GulpFile and also there getting same error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '../components/maininput.jsx'
```

EDIT:
I have found out that it is working only if I provide full path to component, which is strange. Anyone knows what might cause this problem? Probably some enviroment variable or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `./` at the beginning of your import path:

```
import { MainInput } from './components/maininput.jsx'
```