# Npm build using Cloudflare Pages results in 'Cannot Find Module'

Tags: node.js, build, create-react-app, cloudflare-pages

i'm trying to upload my create-react-app site to Cloudflare Pages, and everything's been going great, However, when I add this line: `import NotFoundPage from "pages/NotFound.js";` of code to my App.js, it throws a rather odd error:

```
22:57:43.995    Failed to compile.
22:57:43.996    
22:57:43.996    ./src/App.js
22:57:43.996    Cannot find module: 'pages/NotFound.js'. Make sure this package is installed.
22:57:43.996    
22:57:43.996    You can install this package by running: npm install pages/NotFound.js.
```

What makes this even more confusing, is the code right above it works completely fine:

```
import PrivacyPolicyPage from "pages/PrivacyPolicy.js";
import TermsOfUsePage from "pages/TermsOfUse.js";
import NotFoundPage from "pages/NotFound.js";
```

Is anyone aware of why this is happening, and most importantly, why the app is building on my home environment (Windows 11) and not Cloudflare Pages?

The code of `NotFound.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import ScrollToTop from 'components/ScrollToTop';
import NotFound from 'components/NotFound';
import Sidebar from 'components/Sidebar';
import Navbar from 'components/Navbar';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';

function NotFoundPage() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/notfound.css" />
      </Helmet>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      <Navbar noFade toggle={toggle} />
      <NotFound />
      <Footer sticky />
    </>
  );
}

export default NotFoundPage;
```

And `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "pages";
import PrivacyPolicyPage from "pages/PrivacyPolicy.js";
import TermsOfUsePage from "pages/TermsOfUse.js";
import NotFoundPage from "pages/NotFound.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyPage} exact />
        <Route path="/terms-of-use" component={TermsOfUsePage} exact />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NOTE: I have tried it with `./` at the start of the import string, tried adding `{}` around the import object, and neither of those work either, throwing the same error. [npm build with Browserify - Error: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754599/npm-build-with-browserify-error-cannot-find-module) did not help.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by (and I know how odd this sounds) renaming the `pages` directory to `page`. My guess is that Cloudflare is doing some weird stuff with that, but I can't really be sure.